# Retrieving App Store application icon URL with PHP

Tags: php, app-store

I found that App Store API support additional information about application.

```
$keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
$appstore_api = 'http://itunes.apple.com/search?country=US&entity=software&term='.$keyword;
$data = file_get_contents($appstore_api);
echo $data;
```

here is the PHP code that I wrote.

I get this result.

{ "resultCount":50, "results": [ {"kind":"software", "features":[], "supportedDevices":["all"], "isGameCenterEnabled":false, "artistViewUrl":"http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/burbn-inc./id389801255?uo=4", "artworkUrl60":"http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/105/Purple/v4/f3/0e/e2/f30ee271-c564-ec21-02d6-d020bd2ff38b/Icon.png", "screenshotUrls":["http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/102/Purple/v4/2d/25/d3/2d25d348-74e9-8365-208c-45e64af73ed6/mzl.xnvocmpt.png", "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/077/Purple/v4/04/18/b3/0418b375-c0c1-18c1-1aef-07555c99af46/mzl.pkthtqtv.png", "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/069/Purple/v4/31/08/65/31086528-2f37-bca0-71f3-c3095e698f35/mza_8774562250786021670.png", "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/091/Purple/v4/95/a2/65/95a265bb-b9f0-8732-9fe4-823ffbc9aba0/mza_5807950548098772841.png"], "ipadScreenshotUrls":[], "artworkUrl512":"http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/089/Purple/v4/44/76/7f/44767fb5-4cb2-25bf-5361-25138b8c2aeb/mzl.ntalagmr.png",

The question is that how can I extract the variable named "artworkUrl512" ?

I tried like this but failed.

```
$image_url = $data->results->artworkUrl512;
$image_url2 = $data['results']['artworkUrl512'];
```

Can you help me how to extract icon image url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$data` is json encoded. Use `json_decode()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['results'][0]['artworkUrl512'];
```